# Saxon HE - XSLT Transform - Getting error when trying to run command line code

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I am working on an XSLT assignment for class. The instructions tell me to "generate the result document horizons.xml by applying the getEmployees template within the alldepartments.xsl stylesheet."

So, I pulled up the terminal and entered: java net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:getEmployees alldepartments.xsl -o:horizons.xml

I got the error message: "Error: Could not find or load main class net.sf.saxon.Transform
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.sf.saxon.Transform"

I attempted to troubleshoot the issue and found instructions to check if the software is working at https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation10/about/gettingstarted/gettingstartedjava.html

So I entered the following into the command line:

java -cp c:\saxon\saxon-he-10.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -t -qs:"current-date()"

All that the Terminal outputs is: function dquote>

To be honest, I'm not certain how to install Saxon beyond unzipping the file I downloaded and placing it in my applications folder on my Mac (Big Sur 11.3.1). I tried to open the .jar file by right-clicking and selecting open, but it gave me the error message:

"The operation couldn't be completed. Failed to execute /Library/internet plug-ins/javaappletplugin.plugin/contents/home/bin/java: no such file or directory"

Here is my JRE version: "16.0.1" 2021-04-20
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-24)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-24, mixed mode, sharing)

Here is my JDK version: javac 16.0.1

The photo is of the inside of the SaxonHE10-5J folder, and I tried to run the saxon-he-10.5.jar file.

I have no idea why things are not working, or what to do next. I'd really appreciate some step-by-step help. Please let me know what other information you need to assist me.

[image: SaxonHE10]

Answer (score 1):

Well, your first attempt failed because Saxon wasn't on the classpath. I think you worked that out. To fix that, you need something like:

```
java -cp c:\saxon\saxon-he-10.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:getEmployees alldepartments.xsl -o:horizons.xml
```

I'm afraid your second attempt (running XQuery) is a bit of a mystery to me. But I'm puzzled why you would be using a Windows file name in the -cp option, when you say you are running on a Mac? If you've installed Saxon into the applications folder on your Mac, then the classpath should be something like `/Users/Nikofem/Applications/Saxon/saxon-he-10.5.jar`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out! I updated the command line code to: java -cp /Users/me/SaxonHE10-5J/saxon-he-10.5.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:getEmployees /Users/me/SaxonHE10-5J/alldepartments.xsl -o:horizons.xml but now it gives me the error: getEmployees template does not exist.

Comment: @Nikofem, that sounds like a new, different problem to getting Saxon setup and run and now rather depends on your XSLT code. Consider to ask a new question for that with a minimal but complete sample of your XSLT and the XML that allows others to reproduce the error.